# Need Help in Using the Stack Exchange Chat Rooms in Mobile?

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

Hi Friends,

I have a nokia mobile, with the help of E-Buddy,NimBuzz, i was able to login in FaceBook, yahoo, gtalk with the help of these application , similarly i was curious to know whether any application similar to E buddy , Nimbuzz, which helps to me to login in the chat rooms of stack Exchange Site , so that i can be in online in these chat rooms through mobile and help others with the help of My mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than some community projects creating an IRC and an XMPP bridge, there is no (official) way for other clients to connect to the chat.

However, there is a version of the chat that is optimized for mobile *browsers*. It is shown automatically if we know that it works fine for the requesting browser (it's officially tested in the Android browser and Mobile Safari).

If your mobile browser isn't on that list, you can *force* mobile mode by appending `?mobile=1` to the room URL.

Let us know if the mobile version works fine on your phone, then we can add the user agent to the list of browsers that automatically get this version.